# Moving shelved files from one Workspace to another workspace

Tags: perforce

Hi I have two workspaces of different locations which have the same folder and file structures. Basically they are the forks of same workspaces.

I have some changes in my shelved files in 1st worksapce which i want to move to 2nd workspace. Using perfoce gui, i edited my 2nd workspace and mapped the 1st with it.

I then ran p4 command

```
    p4 unshelve -s 100001 -c 1000002
```

where 100001 is shelved files in 1st workspace and 100002 is 2nd workspace pending changelist.

This put all those files into my 2nd workspace and it looks like it is done.

But i see files in pending changelist 100002 as `//workspace//1stworksapce//.../abc.h` and when i try to diff it keeps diffing with 1st workspace files.

Opening the files in pending changelist 100002 however, opens the files in 2nd workspace.

Un-mapping 1st workspace makes pending changelist angry and it says files are not mapped..

What do i need to do to make my pending changelist 100002 love its own workspace and not fiddle with 1st workspace anymore ?

Or is there any other way ?

My perforce version is 2014.2

- My method of mapping the two workspace is using `edit workspace` by right clicking on workspace-list in gui and adding entry in `workspace mappings`. I noticed that whatever remains at bottom wins.. making me feel that it may not be a right way.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't actually make a second workspace. Instead you kept the same workspace and changed its mapings. http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/intro/index.html#how_perforce_works.applications.workspace

Comment: To make a second workspace, use connections > new workspace: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Displaying_client_specifications.html